# I'm having trouble importing a hand-created theme pack. Where do I seek help?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have written a `.theme` file by hand and packed it into a CAB file. Then I renamed the file to `.deskthemepack` and double-clicked it in Explorer. It tells me

> Windows can't save this theme to your computer

I've done almost everything and am looking for some help for the theme pack I've created. Now I'm unsure where to ask.

To me, this question is not directly programming-related, so I don't think Stack Overflow is a good place to ask. Super User is also unlikely accepting this question because a regular user would create a theme pack via Control Panel instead of by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be on topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com), I suspect.

Some users actually like doing stuff like that. And pain.

Comment: Well here's a mod's word so I'm going to ask there.

Comment: Having seen the question - on topic for us